# Cross-platform C++ sound library that isn't GPL/LGPL?

Tags: c++, audio

Looking for any simple sound libraries for playback in windows that isn't GPL or LGPL. That is, the software itself isn't AND any library back ends it uses are not GPL/LGPL.

I've been searching for a long time and everything I find that looks promising (Allegro, SFML etc) turns out to have some GPL or LGPL code in it. I'm not trying to start a debate about licensing, it's just my preference so anyone who knows of something simple please let me know.

I'm not necessarily looking for a cross platform solution, but I don't want to rely on built-in Windows methods like PlaySound either.. :). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Just to be clear on what I mean by simple, this is about the most functionality I require:

1. Provide file name or data in memory to a play function.
2. If possible, define callback for when sound is finished.

Comment: What's the problem with LGPL? It does not put restrictions on your code as long as you only link to it (IIRC).

Comment: Like I said it's more a matter of preference and I don't want to get into debating these things, but I guess I'll just say there are some obscure passages in the full license if you read it. Example, there is wording like, if your program becomes "dependent" on "types" within the library, even while linking dynamically, your code must become LGPL as well. I've invested approximately 6 months of my life into writing a cross platform game engine and I'd really like to not give away 6 months of my life for free, even if the chances are extremely small. :)

Comment: If you don't need cross platform, why aren't you willing to use something like DirectSound?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because I'm using back ends for android etc that are not cross platform themselves, so I'm basically doing unique implementations for each. What I said was I don't want to use things like the PlaySound method in windows, namely because it has a lot of issues over different versions of windows, issues with things like async playback etc. As for using just plain directsound, from what I have researched into it, it provides no simple interface as I've expressed would be preferable. However, I understand if there is no small lib that simplifies this I'll have to suck it up and learn. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[libsoundio](http://libsound.io/) is a bit lower level than what you are asking for, but it is robust and MIT licensed.

Answer (score 7):

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) is a low level sound library (in C) which uses the equivalent of an MIT licence

Answer (score 4):

http://aumiks.googlecode.com

```
aumiks::Lib aumiksLibrary(100, aumiks::STEREO_16_44100);
ting::Ref<aumiks::WavSound> snd = aumiks::WavSound::LoadWAV("sample.wav");
ting::Ref<aumiks::Channel> ch = snd->Play();
```

Comment: Marking your answer as correct because I'd much rather use just a sound library than a full library just for the audio portion, as I was doing with SDL. Thanks for joining stack overflow to post this answer!

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more digging around, I managed to find a couple of libraries that are suitable:

Cinder
http://libcinder.org/

Example of use (Audio):

```
audio::SourceRef mAudioSource;
mAudioSource = audio::load( loadResource( MY_RESOURCE ) );
audio::Output::play( mAudioSource );
```

TempAU
http://www.tempau.com/

```
Sound sound("somefile.mp3"); // Create sound object
sound.play();                // Play it!
```

The source for TempAU has not yet been released as it's brand new. I've seen some comments on forums by the developer and he is planning to release it in the near future, from what I gather. TempAU right now uses libs that are LGPL so I'm not going to use it, but I thought I'd mention it anyway since once the source comes out I'm sure it'd be trivial to link in ogg support or something open.

Cinder is licensed under a modified BSD license, so pretty much the only license requirement is that you include a copy of the license anywhere (ReadMe, whatever) when distributing with your source or binaries. Since I've already written the vast majority of the functionality in cinder, I'm just going to strip out the audio part and built it into it's own lib. Thanks again, hope this is helpful!

**Edit**
One last thing, I stumbled upon both these libraries from this excellent list of libs. The list provides a short description of functionality within each lib, along with what license the library is published under.

http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Libraries

**Edit...again**
SDL, as of verion 1.3+ is [zlib licensed](http://freegamer.blogspot.com/2011/04/sdllicense-zlib-sdllicense-lgpl-true.html).

**One last edit...**
I've been speaking with the developer of TempAU and he has released the source code on google code under the new BSD license.

http://code.google.com/p/tempau/

Answer (score 1):

[IrrKLang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) is not GPL (It is a commercial product):

> irrKlang is a high level 2D and 3D cross platform (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) sound engine and audio library ... can be accessed via an extremely simple API.

I've already used it and it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am planning on producing a commercial game and right now I'm on the mr.noodles diet so shelling out cash for a license right now isn't necessarily an option. lol :D

Comment: Wait, so you need a non-LGPL/GPL sound system AND it must be free for commerical use? That's a pretty weird set of restrictions it must be said - you're going to be hard pushed to find audio libraries using FLOSS licences which aren't LGPL/GPL

Answer (score 1):

[BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) is "free for non-commercial use" without naming a third-party licence (it looks the same as the MIT licence to me, but IANAL), and I've always enjoyed working with its C API.

Their pricing for per-product commercial licences is pretty reasonable, too.